# Windows Mobile (MFC). Application falls down when has a lot of bmp pictures?

Tags: memory, mfc, windows-mobile, bitmap, bmp

I use visual studio 2008, mfc smart device project, imate jasjar with windows mobile 2005.

My application works. Then I simply add some pictures as resources inside the project. App will not work after this action.
Application can work with bmp images only (because of specific windows mobile 2005 features). So I have 24-bit pictures and 32-bit pictures (with alpha-channel).
I compile the application as cab installation file.

Can you advice me a solution? I have two ideas, but I even don't know is it possible:
1)To load pictures of another format and to convert them into bmp anyway.
2)To make these pictures files which are separate from executable of application.

Comment: Both versions can be done. Which would you prefer? Have you started any code?

Comment: I want those version which will be workable. I think it is simplier and faster to replace all the bmp files with png files. But the program work still will has been depending on the amout of images.
Now I try to use Gdiplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with too large exe file. I simply deleted the biggest images without alpha-channel from the project and wrote the code to load them from the same folder. I used SHLoadImageFile which supports an enough count of file extentions.
Then I created the cab file (in visual studio) without these pictures. Then I edited this cab with "wince cab manager" to simply add the pictures in the same app folder after installation.